# Attribute value nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

I have created a social networking website using Ruby on Rails. This is my first time programming with RoR.

I have a model named "Friendship" which contains an attribute "blocked" to indicate whether the user has blocked another user.

When I run the following in IRB -

```
friendship = u.friendships.where(:friend_id => 22).first
```

IRB gives me -

```
  Friendship Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `friendships`.* FROM `friendships` WHERE `friendships`.`user_id` = 17 AND `friendships`.`friend_id` = 22 LIMIT 1
=> #<Friendship id: 33, user_id: 17, friend_id: 22, created_at: "2012-04-07 10:29:49", updated_at: "2012-04-07 10:29:49", blocked: 1>
```

As u can see, the "blocked" attribute has value '1'.

But when I run the following

```
1.9.2-p290 :030 > friendship.blocked    
=> nil
```

- it says, the value of blocked is 'nil' and not '1'.
Why is this happening?
This could be a very silly mistake but I am new to RoR, so kindly help me!

I initially didn't include the accessor method for 'blocked'.. I tried that, and still its giving the same result..
Following is the Friendship model..

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
    validates_uniqueness_of :friend_id , :scope => :user_id

    attr_accessor :blocked
    attr_accessible :blocked
end
```

Here is the schema of the table:

```
1.9.2-p290 :009 > friendship.class
=> Friendship(id: integer, user_id: integer, friend_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, blocked: integer)
```

Comment: Do you have `attr_accessor :blocked` in your model? That would cause this.

Comment: I did add the accessor method and tried again.. but its still nil..

Comment: > - it says, the value of blocked is 'nil' and not '0': but it should be 1, shouldn't it? Can you include schema for that table?

Comment: You don't need `attr_accessor :blocked` if this is a persistent field (in the database). What data type is this field?

Comment: Ernest - Yes, it should be 1 and not 0.. I have added the schema of the table..

Comment: DanS is right, you don't need attr_accessor :blocked. Instead you should put all fields that need to be public in attr_accessible, and here is why: http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment-revised

Comment: DanS - it is of type Integer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`attr_accessor :blocked` creates two methods:

```
def blocked
  @blocked
end

def blocked=val
  @blocked = val
end
```

And this rewrites AR `blocked` method, which should return attribute value

So you should remove this line from your code.

Comment: Thanks fl00r, I tried using just the attr_reader method too.. but its still giving me a 'nil' value..

Comment: @mridula yes, because attr_reader creates getter method (while accessor creates getter and also a setter), and it overrides AR's #blocked too.